# solving equations with log and polynomials.

Tags: analysis

I need to solve/estimate for x in the following equation -

$Klnx + x^\beta = r$.

$K,r > 0.$

An estimate for large r(fixed K) is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation has solution in terms of Lambert function $$K \log(x) + x^\beta - r=0$$ gives $$x=\left(\frac{K W\left(\frac{\beta  \left(e^{\frac{r}{K}}\right)^{\beta
   }}{K}\right)}{\beta }\right)^{\frac{1}{\beta }}$$ It could have been more obvious defining $x^\beta=y$ and rewriting the equation as $$\frac{K }{\beta }\log (y)+y-r=0$$  $$y=\frac{K }{\beta }W\left(\frac{\beta  e^{\frac{\beta  r}{K}}}{K}\right)$$ and to remember that any equation which can write $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has a solution in terms of Lambert function.

Now, for large values of the argument, there are very good approximations of $W(x)$. Just look at the asymptotic expansions at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function